# Insufficient disk space when restoring or resizing db on SQL Server 2019 dev ed

Tags: sql-server, restore

Strange problem: I'm trying to restore AdventureWorks2019 from the downloaded backup file and constantly receive the error

> SQL Error [3257] [S0001]: There is insufficient free space on disk
> volume 'C:' to create the database. The database requires 285212672
> additional free bytes, while only 142028800 bytes are available.
> There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'C:' to create the
> database. The database requires 285212672 additional free bytes, while
> only 142028800 bytes are available.   There is insufficient free space
> on disk volume 'C:' to create the database. The database requires
> 285212672 additional free bytes, while only 142028800 bytes are
> available.

although drive C: contains 21+GiB of free space.

Attempting the restore from SSMS or via SQL restore-command doesn't make a difference.

I tried to free up the ›additional amount‹, nevertheless, but to no avail.

Backup and restore of a test database worked, although it changed the number of available bytes in the error message for AdventureWorks. So I figure, SQL Server is actually looking in the right folder. The very backup file *can* be restored in a different instance (2022) of SQL Server, so it's not some hidden log exploding in size (which would yield different numbers, anyway).

The SQL Server was updated with "KB5029377 - security update for SQL Server 2019 GDR", but this also changed nothing.

Resetting the read-only flag on the data folder also didn't change anything.

As I don't have the slightest idea, why or even how wrong numbers might be reported, I'm somewhat out of options… Any ideas, anyone? (Is this maybe even a known behaviour? I've found nothing on it but an 11 y/o thread on stackoverflow.)

Add: Exporting the database as data-tier and importing the .bacpac-file on the server in question also didn't work, with the same error: Insufficient disk space.

So that server seemingly actually sees a wrong free size in its data folder!?

Add2: Un- and reinstalling the SQL Server also yielded no effect. Still the same error.

Add3: A different instance name, a different data folder name and reinstalling with download option and from iso-image also accomplished nothing.

Comment: Two things that occur to me. One, have you implemented file-system quotas? If so, the quota for the MSSQL user or database folder might really be that small despite the amount of uncommitted disk space. Two, the fact that it sees only 142MB available when there is 21GB free is suspiciously like the disk overflow that happened when disks outgrew the size that many programs could handle. Have you tried creating junk files to decrease available disk space?

Comment: First of all: Thank you!

No quotas. (In the default instance, I can create databases as large as I want.)

The 2nd hint I don't quite understand. What I hadn't mentioned is a disk check went without errors. You mean, I should fill the disk? I can of course do that – but what do I find out? And how?

Comment: I'LL BE DAMNED! There IS a disk quota! Thanks a lot! (I'd never have found that on my own!) Cheers!

Comment: If you'e OK with this, I'll post this again as an answer. That way, someone else who has the same problem is more likely to use this solution. Especially if you accept it - you'll have the option of clicking a check mark to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unusual for MSSQL and the file system to disagree on disk sizes. There was a while, a long time ago, where programs would not understand about disks bigger than some value (2G? 4G? 8G? Yes, it has been a long time.) and would look at (e.g.) a 4.5GB disk and lose the 4GB part, thinking the disk was only 0.5GB. This is very unlikely for a 2019 program, though.

Much more likely is that somehow a disk quota has been set, either on the MSSQL user or on the MSSQL data folder. That would actually be high on my list of things to check, particularly as the amount of free space is fairly close to a "round number", in this case 150MB.

Comment: In this case, thare actually HAD been a quota: For new users! (And this is why the default instance was able to create any database, whereas the newly installed instance with its new Windows service account couldn't.)